# Creating an update.zip for android phone

Tags: android, zip, updates

having some trouble making an update.zip for my Samsung Galaxy Apollo android phone.
I was making my first update.zip by trying to push an apk file into /system/app.
Below is the content of updater-script.

```
ui_print("Installing Titanium Backup6.0.2");
package_extract_file("system/app/TitaniumBackup602.apk","/system/app/TitaniumBackup602.apk");
set_perm(1000, 1000, 0664, "/system/app/TitaniumBackup602.apk");
ui_print("Done.");
```

Everytime I flash it gives **Installation aborted** error.
also I am confused about the update-binary file.Some say we should just copy paste the working  binary file into our update.zip but I have two files(each of different sizes) both working with the zips they came along but surprisingly I am still getting the same error.

Any more info required?
Please help.This is really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll have to mount the `/system` partition (with read and write permissions).  This could be achived via

```
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/mmcblk0p25", "/system");
```

where `p25` must be set to the correct partition and `EMMC` or `MTC` has to be the right partition type.

At least, this is what I see when I look up an `updater-script` (`META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script` in the ZIP file) from some custom rom -- maybe get one of these and try to modify them.

Comment: The /system was mounted through CWM.I used the built-in feature of Titanium to create an update.zip but the binary file packed in it didn't work so I replaced it with the one from the phone's xda forum and it worked.